# ConvertFrom-Json max length

Tags: json, powershell

I have a problem using PowerShell v3 when converting JSON strings over 2MB in size. The default limit in JSON serializer used by PowerShell is set to 2MB which explains the error.

However when I deserialize object using ConvertFrom-Json on a smaller set (I got various data objects with smaller and bigger internal collections but those are the same objects) it returns very nice object with all properties which I can easily access.

To overcome the limitations of the serializer I tried to deserialize data by hand:

```
$jsser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$jsser.MaxJsonLength = $jsser.MaxJsonLength * 10
$jsser.RecursionLimit = 99    

$outObject = $jsser.DeserializeObject($json)
```

The object looks differently it seems that internal collections were not deserialized and when I try to execute properties they return empty results.

My questions:

1. Assumption is `ConvertFrom-Json` does some additional magic or somehow creates a template for the object before serialization. Any idea how to replicate it?
2. The object I get is always a `PSCustomObject`; if I get the object I want setup by `ConvertFrom-Json` is there anyway to use it as object type in JsonSerializer?

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it like this:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")        
$jsonserial= New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer 
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength  = 67108864
$Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($CourseTypesResponse)
```

You can use `$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength` to manipulate the MaxJsonLength property

source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/833c99c1-d8eb-400d-bf58-38f7265b4b0e/error-when-converting-from-json?forum=winserverpowershell&prof=required

Answer (score 6):

I had the same propblem when using `Invoke-RestMethod` and large JSON collections in the result. I ended up adapting the methods from [Parsing json with PowerShell and Json.NET](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/parsing-json-with-powershell-and-json-net/) to convert JSON Collections to PowerShell Objects.

```
# .NET JSON Serializer 
$global:javaScriptSerializer = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$global:javaScriptSerializer.MaxJsonLength = [System.Int32]::MaxValue
$global:javaScriptSerializer.RecursionLimit = 99

# Functions necessary to parse JSON output from .NET serializer to PowerShell Objects
function ParseItem($jsonItem) {
        if($jsonItem.PSObject.TypeNames -match "Array") {
                return ParseJsonArray($jsonItem)
        }
        elseif($jsonItem.PSObject.TypeNames -match "Dictionary") {
                return ParseJsonObject([HashTable]$jsonItem)
        }
        else {
                return $jsonItem
        }
}

function ParseJsonObject($jsonObj) {
        $result = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
        foreach ($key in $jsonObj.Keys) {
                $item = $jsonObj[$key]
                if ($item) {
                        $parsedItem = ParseItem $item
                } else {
                        $parsedItem = $null
                }
                $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $key -Value $parsedItem
        }
        return $result
}

function ParseJsonArray($jsonArray) {
        $result = @()
        $jsonArray | ForEach-Object {
                $result += , (ParseItem $_)
        }
        return $result
}

function ParseJsonString($json) {
        $config = $javaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject($json)
        return ParseJsonObject($config)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, it's better to replace `return ParseJsonObject($config)` with `return ParseItem($config)` as `DeserializeObject` might return array.

Comment: Why do you set `$global:javaScriptSerializer.RecursionLimit` to 99? Default is 100.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me quite well over the years:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Web.Extensions

function get-Json($data) {
    $json = [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]::new()
    $json.MaxJsonLength = 104857600
    $out = $json.Deserialize($data, [System.Object])
    return $out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this in my code :

```
JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
oSerializer.MaxJsonLength *= 2;
ws_Out = (ClsWsOut)oSerializer.Deserialize(jsonOut, ws_Out.GetType());
```

Where ws_Out.GetType() is a classe I define to parse the json.

```
public class ClsLogin_In :ClsWsIn
{
  public string login { get; set; }
  public string passwd { get; set; }
}

public class ClsLogin_Out : ClsWsOut
{
  public int error { get; set; }
  public string error_desc { get; set; }
  public int key { get; set; }
}
```

---

Edited

in PowerShell V3 when the json returned by a web service is very big the PowerShell V3 is sending an exception.
So I use XML serialisation, here is my function, it also use an external assemblies, but they are basic ones, XML is a bit verbose but it works.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.ServiceModel.Web, System.Runtime.Serialization
$utf8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8    

function Write-String

{
  PARAM([Parameter()]$stream,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$string)

  PROCESS
  {
    $bytes = $utf8.GetBytes($string)
    $stream.Write( $bytes, 0, $bytes.Length )
  }  
}

function Convert-JsonToXml

{
  PARAM([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$json)

  BEGIN
  { 
    $mStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream 
  }

  PROCESS
  {
    $json | Write-String -stream $mStream
  }

  END
  {
    $mStream.Position = 0
    try
    {
       $jsonReader = [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory]::CreateJsonReader($mStream,[System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas]::Max)
       $xml = New-Object Xml.XmlDocument
       $xml.Load($jsonReader)
       $xml
    }
    finally
    {
       $jsonReader.Close()
       $mStream.Dispose()
    }
  }
}

function Convert-XmlToJson
{
  PARAM([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][Xml]$xml)

  PROCESS
  {
    $mStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    $jsonWriter = [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonReaderWriterFactory]::CreateJsonWriter($mStream)
    try
    {
      $xml.Save($jsonWriter)
      $bytes = $mStream.ToArray()
      [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)
    }
    finally
    {
      $jsonWriter.Close()
      $mStream.Dispose()
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example.

```
$json = @'
{
  "data": {
    "langid": 7, 
    "results": [{
       "first_aired": "2010-11-15", 
        "name": "Accused", 
       "tvdbid": 72663
       }, 
       {
       "first_aired": "2010-01-17", 
       "name": "Enzai: Falsely Accused", 
       "tvdbid": 135881
       }]
  }, 
  "message": "", 
  "result": "success"
}
'@

$xmlOut = Convert-JsonToXml -json $json
($xmlOut.root.data.results).ChildNodes[0].tvdbid.InnerText
($xmlOut.root.data.results).ChildNodes[1].tvdbid.InnerText
```

Comment: Yes but in powershell I'm trying to avoid importing .Net dlls
Powershell has it's own dynamic objects which are populated with properties on the fly and it was working great with files under 2MB. I just want to force it work the same way with files above 2MB.

Comment: To be full PowerShell you can use XML. I use it in my PowerShell V2.0 scripts. It supports big jsons, but it's a bit verbose to use.

Comment: If you look on my original question, I already found a way to deserialize large JSON. When you instantiate serializer yourself you can change MaxJsonLength property. You will have to use Invoke-WebRequest rather than Invoke-RestRequest and than follow RawContent and look for the first '{' and remove everything from infront and you have a clean json. On large objects this Xml serialization might take it's toll.