# Powershell ConvertFrom-JSON File Size

Tags: powershell

What is the max file size for Powershell Version 5.0 that the ConvertFrom-JSON can handle? I know 2MB is for version 4, but what is it for 5.0 and 6.0?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854057/convertfrom-json-max-length

Comment: That's not for version 5.