# Azure DevOps - get custom Task Reference ID

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to update a Pipeline with the [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API call.

That works fine, but when I want to add a **custom task** (self made build pipeline task extension) then I struggeling to find the correct **task reference id**:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The pipeline is not valid. A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called '7f1fe94f-b811-4ba1-9d6a-b6c27de758d7'. This 
usually indicates the task isn't installed, and you may be able to install it from the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com. (Task version 1.*, job 'Job_1', step ''.),Job Job_1: Step  
has an invalid task definition reference. A valid task definition reference must specify either an ID or a name and a version specification with a major version 
specified.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Pipelines.PipelineValidationException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi","typeKey":"PipelineValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

I check out the `registrationId` of my custom task with the [Installed Extensions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/extensionmanagement/installed%20extensions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API call. But it is not the correct one. (`7f1fe94f-b811-4ba1-9d6a-b6c27de758d7`)

I also add the **custom task** manually to a pipeline and read out the correct task refernce id with the [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API call. I could find the id in:

```
$pipeline.process.phases.steps.task.id -> 2c7efb3e-3267-4ac6-addc-86e88a6dab34
```

[image]

---

**But how can I read out this id without adding the custom task manually?**

This id is obviously dynamic and changes everytime when the custom task get installed, so there must be a way to get this refernce.

Comment: Is it a task from the Marketplace or it's your own task?

Comment: It's a custom task, created by my own.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk thanks for the hint Shayki. The ID is written inside the `task.json`. Thank you a lot for that. But I there a way to get this ID directly from the Azure DevOps Server? It must have these information, but where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task id has not changed every time when the custom task gets installed, but he existed in `task.json` of the task:

```
{
    "id": "2f159376-f4dk-4311-a49c-392f9d534113",
    "name": "TaskName",
    "friendlyName": "Task Name",
```

Another option is to use this api:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organiztion}/_apis/distributedtask/tasks
```

You will get a long list of all the tasks, search your task and you will see the id.

Comment: It's hard to find if it is not documented, thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: **In addition:** the API call returns potentially a very long `json` response. I had problems to generate an object with PowerShells `Invoke-RestMethod` or `ConvertFrom-Json`. I found to answer to handle very long jsons here: [ConvertFrom-Json max length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854057/convertfrom-json-max-length). **Error Message was:** `Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. 
Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.`

Comment: glad i found this. this rest api is so badly / not documented that it is sometimes hard to find what you need. i wanted to add to this that if you already know the id of the task and don't want to run into issues with long lists you can use this api: `https://dev.azure.com/{organiztion}/_apis/distributedtask/tasks/{taskid}` it will return the specific task with al its installed versions. for me it is used in grabbing the extension details (maker + name) from the release definition where i have the taskid available. taskid is not available in the extensions api (for unknown reasons)